# AngularJS Factory Service not returning dynamic data to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my factory service and it is fetching data from a web service

```
var customersFactory = function ($http) {
    var customer = [];
    var getCustomersURL = "http://localhost:50340/Services/CustomerService.asmx/GetCustomers";

    customer.XMLtoJSON = function (data) {
        data = data.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', ''); ;
        data = data.replace('<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">', '').replace('</string>', '');
        return $.parseJSON(data);
    };

    customer.GetCustomers = function () {
        $http.post(getCustomersURL).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return customer.XMLtoJSON(data);
        }).error(function (ata, status, headers, config) {  });
    };

    return customer;
};

app.factory('customersFactory', customersFactory);
```

Now, this is being used in my controller

```
app.controller("CustomersController", function ($scope, customersFactory) {
    var service = [];
    service = customersFactory.GetCustomers();
    $scope.Customers = service;

    if ((typeof (service) != 'undefined') && service.length > 0) {
        service.then(function (result) {
            $scope.Customers = result;
        });
    }
});
```

The value of service is always undefined or empty. Data is not being passed from factory to controller. Im calling a simple web service, no fancy APIs or WCF.

It there was some static/dummy data, its working fine. The controller is fetching the data and is being displayed.

Where am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change this line `var customer = [];` to this `var customer = {};`

Or better yet make it a class...

change this to return the promise:

```
customer.GetCustomers = function () {
        return $http.post(getCustomersURL).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  });
    };
```

and usage in the controller:

```
app.controller("CustomersController", function($scope, customersFactory) {
  $scope.Customers = [];

  customersFactory.getCustomers().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.Customers = customersFactory.XMLtoJSON(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot WalksAway. Got this. I understood where I went wrong. Really thanks a lot.